# How do I prevent a Terraform Module from creating duplicate API Gateway Resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I've created a Module which will create an `aws_api_gateway_resource`, an `aws_api_gateway_method` and an `aws_api_gateway_integration`. It will also optionally create a "root" `aws_api_gateway_resource` which has a count parameter:

```
 count = "${var.path_prefix != "" ? 1 : 0}"
```

so that I can call it multiple times to do something like:

```
/
    /api
        /foo
        /bar
```

by passing in an optional `path_prefix`. In this instance that value is `api`.

However, it actually creates the following structure:

```
/
    /api
        /foo
        /bar
    /api
```

When the module is called a second time to create the `bar` it sees that there is already a root `api` resource, and correctly attaches the new resource to that existing resource. However, it also creates a new one since the `path_prefix` variable exists. How do I prevent that?

Comment: What benefit are you seeing from this module? This feels like a really bad fit for modules here. API Gateways are a real pain to manage with Terraform due to the API Gateway lifecycle management being very different to how Terraform does things so I'd be very wary of splitting up an API gateway definition across multiple modules.

Comment: My goal is to create a module that our developers can use to quickly build out an API based on only having to use a single module per resource. If they only have to fill in a handful of parameters per module, as opposed to one per resource + method + integration + response code then the uptake will be much quicker. Hopefully it will also be easier to maintain.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that worked in a nice way. Have you considered looking at something like using OpenAPI spec to define the API gateway instead? Then devs can just specify their OpenAPI spec and have the API Gateway automatically configured correctly.